# append all results of get_all_tweets_count with Paginator from tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tweepy

im struggeling to get the results from my tweepy count into usabale format.

Im using the elevated Twitter access and the tweepy package.

```
counts = tweepy.Paginator(
        client.get_all_tweets_count,
        query=query, start_time=start_time,
        end_time=end_time,
        granularity='day') time.sleep(1)"
    
    
tweet_count = []
    
for count in counts:
        tweet_count.append(count.data)
```

Im getting as a result my Dataframe as a list of dictionaries.

The result is looking like:

Basically i have a output which is like:

```
data = [[{'end': '2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'start': '2020-11-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'tweet_count': 5780}, {'end': '2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'start': '2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'tweet_count': 3093}, {'end': '2020-12-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'start': '2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'tweet_count': 7379},...}]]
```

How can i get a nice DataFrame with pandas for example which looks like:

```
   Start                     End                       Count
0  2020-11-30T00:00:00.000Z  2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z  5780  
1  2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z  2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z  3093      
2  ...                        ...                      ...
```

Im not that good in python but i guess i miss something with the format in list with dictionaries inside.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data[0])` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the nested list then use pandas's `DataFrame()` constructor to build your dataframe.

```
from itertools import chain
data = list(chain.from_iterable(data))

df = pd.DataFrame(data).reindex(['start', 'end', 'tweet_count'], axis=1)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

                      start                       end  tweet_count
0  2020-11-30T00:00:00.000Z  2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z         5780
1  2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z  2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z         3093
2  2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z  2020-12-03T00:00:00.000Z         7379
```